# Solution of $(n-2) \cdot x^n - (n-1) \cdot x + 1 = 0$ in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n \geqslant 3$ be a fixed natural number. Consider an equation
$$
 (n-2) \cdot x^n - (n-1) \cdot x + 1 = 0. \tag{1}
$$

This equation has real solutions:

- $\{1, x_0, x_1\}$, where $x_0 \in (0,1)$ and $x_1 < 0$, if $n$ is odd,
- $\{1, x_0\}$, where $x_0 \in (0,1)$, if $n$ is even.

(Evidently $x_0$ and $x_1$ depend on $n$.)

Is there a method to obtain the formula for $x_0$, that is for the solution of equation $(1)$ in the interval $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unlikely to be a "closed-form" formula for $x_0$.  For example, when $n=6$
the polynomial
$$ \frac{4 x^6 - 3 x +1}{x-1} = 4\,{x}^{5}+4\,{x}^{4}+4\,{x}^{3}+4\,{x}^{2}+4\,x-1$$
is irreducible over the rationals with Galois group $S_5$, so has no roots expressible in radicals.

As $n \to \infty$, $x_0$ is asymptotically $$ \frac{1}{n-1} + \left(1 - \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{25}{24 n^2} +\ldots \right)e n^{-n} $$